# how to merge the last branch with the master branch

Tags: git

I have a project with several branches :

```
master
branch A on master
branch B on A
branch C on B
branch D on C
etc ...
```

I want the last branch to get back to master. I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by getting the last branch on to master? Do you want to merge it with master or rebase it back onto master?

Comment: What is the dfference between merge and rebase ?

Comment: `git` should allow you to merge any branch into more or less any other branch.  You don't have to do anything different just because one was not forked directly from the other.

Comment: What do you mean by “get back to”? Would you like to undo changes to a branch? Or just get back to making changes on master.

Comment: I sense you misunderstood some core-aspects of git. I recommend looking at https://github.com/tpn/pdfs/blob/master/Git%20from%20the%20Bottom%20Up.pdf (I'd might look like a lot, but it's definitely worth reading)

Comment: just get back to making changes on master

Comment: You do not need to merge anything just to "get back to making changes on master".  You can just check it out.  The question of merging is about what you want to do with changes you made on other branches, and what you may want to do with those branches in the future.

Comment: sorry John, I made a mistake in my comment. I just want to be sure is that I can merge branch_D with master, even if it is not directly linked to it. It appears from your different comments that it is perfectly possible. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at your query I made some assumptions and giving you the following solution: So, you just want to merge branch D on master irrespective of changes in A, B, C, ...? Since you made 3 different branches on top of `master` you need to first merge the latest changes from `master` on to `branch D` (use the commands: `git fetch origin master` && `git merge origin master`). Resolve conflicts, if any. Then go to the `master` branch (`git checkout master`) and merge `branch D` (`git merge branch_D`). Your `master` branch is in sync with `branch D` now.

Comment: why not just `git checkout master && git merge D`?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, **no you do not** need to first merge the master into branch D before merging D into the master.  There are reasons why you might want to do that, but there are also common scenarios in which it is of no particular benefit.

Comment: These steps are a precaution/best practice. As, over the time, someone might've merged into `master` (while you were working on `branch D`). So, better you've the latest changes before merging it back to `master`.

Comment: Also, I think, you get warning message in such cases if your branch is not in sync with master and your branch is rejected.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd just like to start working off the master branch again you can just `checkout` master. That means switching back to working off the master branch.

`git checkout master`

If you then want to merge the changes you've made on branch D you can merge then run:

`git merge branch D`

To see a list of all your current branches you can run:

`git branch`